# Handling blank values from a soap webservice in SoapUI output to Excel

Tags: xpath, soapui

I have a SoapUI project and test suite that reads values from Excel, puts them into a SOAP request, sends the request and gets its response, and writes the response values to another Excel spreadsheet.  So far, so good.

When the web service returns an empty value, however, SoapUI writes a namespace tag to the spreadsheet `<xyz:transactionUID xmlns:xyz="http://xyz.abc.etc">`.  I would like a way to have SoapUI write nothing to the cell when nothing comes back from the web service.

Anyone know how to do this?

EDIT:

Here is the XPath used to write the value to the spreadsheet:

`${myRequest#Response#declare namespace xyz='http://xyz.abc.etc.service'; //xyz:MyOutputWrapper[1]/xyz:MyVerifyResponse[1]/xyz:IdMatchIndicators[1]/xyz:FrstNmMatchInd[1]}`

i.e., this is the 'value' under 'name/value' in the properties for the DataSink step.

Comment: What **exactly** is the value - I assume it is going to be some XPath - that is written?

Comment: I should have thought of putting that in; I've now added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SoapUI takes some *liberties* with your XPath.

First, note that for reading you can greatly simplify your XPath by dropping the namespaces:

```
${myRequest#Response#//*:MyOutputWrapper[1]/*:MyVerifyResponse[1]/*:IdMatchIndicators[1]/*:FrstNmMatchInd[1]}
```

Next, for multiple matches SoapUI will always grab the first:

```
${myRequest#Response#//*:MyOutputWrapper/*:MyVerifyResponse/*:IdMatchIndicators/*:FrstNmMatchInd}
```

Lastly, and this is the **important** one for your case, if the matched node has a `text()` node, SoapUI will use that. If there is no `text()` node, it will give you the whole node ... which is exactly what you are seeing. In your case, because you do not want that behaviour, you need to explicitly state that you want the `text()` node:

```
${myRequest#Response#//*:MyOutputWrapper/*:MyVerifyResponse/*:IdMatchIndicators/*:FrstNmMatchInd/text()}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  I don't know much of anything about XPath, just heard of it doing this with SoapUI, and didn't enter these myself -- the XPath expression as I gave it to you is the one SoapUI enters for me when I choose the node using the SoapUI, uh, UI (including the namespaces).